# Android KeyChain.createInstallIntent returning immediately

Tags: android, android-intent, android-4.4-kitkat

In my Android app, I am trying to install a PKCS12 file (certificate and private key) retrieved from my server. To do this, I am using `KeyChain.createInstallIntent()`. I pass in the file and the name to use as Extras, then use `startActivityForResult` to fire off the activity.

This works fine on my Galaxy Tab 2 running 4.1.1 Jelly Bean, opening up the system dialog to install the certificate as expected. However, on my Galaxy Tab 3 running 4.4.2 KitKat, the `onActivityResult` method is called immediately with a result code of `RESULT_CANCELLED`.

What I'm trying to accomplish is for the app to be notified of the success/failure of the certificate installation, then open a browser window and go to either a success or failure page accordingly.

```
protected void importPkcs12(byte[] pkcs12, String defaultName)
{
    Intent installIntent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
    installIntent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_PKCS12, pkcs12);
    installIntent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_NAME, defaultName);
    startActivityForResult(installIntent, INSTALL_KEYSTORE_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    logger.debug("onActivityResult called with requestCode {}", requestCode);

    switch(requestCode)
    {
        case INSTALL_KEYSTORE_CODE:
        {           
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
               // Go to success web page
            }
            else //RESULT_CANCELED
            {
                // Go to canceled/failure web page  
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: @Were you able to figure out the reason. I am having the same problem as well.

Comment: I was not. Ended up having to refactor so that I could handle it returning immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a ticket for this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=158411.

As a workaround, you could use a BroadcastReceiver with the keystore-changed event to get a notification when the user actually installs the certificate, but that's obviously making a lot of assumptions, and it further doesn't let you catch the actual cancellation event.